# SQL count not working (with mysql_fetch_assoc();)

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to create an admin panel for my website. I use this code on my dashboard to count the number of users (and similar for the blog posts etc.:

```
//get result
$data = mysql_query("SELECT count(user_id) AS total FROM account_users");
$info = mysql_fetch_assoc($data);

//output result
echo "Rows found :" . $info['total'];
```

When I enter this code and view the page, this is the result:

```
Rows found :
```

As you can see, the number is not visible.

I tried to execute the code in the SQL section of PHPMyAdmin, and the result is 1 (and there is 1 row in the database, so that is correct!)

How is this possible? (And can you help me?)

---

Update on first comment:
I added the code he told me to, but it isn't going better.....

Error I'm getting now:

```
Notice: Undefined index: auth in /home/vol9_6/epizy.com/epiz_21854614/admin.ictsupport.ga/htdocs/index.php on line 9

Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in /home/vol9_6/epizy.com/epiz_21854614/admin.ictsupport.ga/htdocs/index.php on line 19

Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in /home/vol9_6/epizy.com/epiz_21854614/admin.ictsupport.ga/htdocs/index.php on line 20
Rows found : 
Notice: Undefined index: username in /home/vol9_6/epizy.com/epiz_21854614/admin.ictsupport.ga/htdocs/nav.php on line 3
```

Comment: Did you turn on error reporting? Put this at the top of your script: `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` ... also, did you open the connection to mysql? Lastly, you need to migrate off of `mysql_*` functions as they are depreciated, and dead in php7+. Go with `mysqli_*` functions, or PDO.

Comment: What is the PHP version you are using ? If its PHP7.0 or PHP7.1 , then use mysqli or PDO . Anyway give a try with this query

SELECT count(user_id) AS 'total' FROM account_users

Let me know if it runs .

Comment: Well, I changed mysql to mysqli, and added the code (as shown in my update), but it isn't going better

Comment: @Rick , if you use mysqli or PDO , then search for proper syntax , you have to pass the connection string though . But before that put my query in traditional method and check whether result is coming or not .

Comment: I included a file called db.php which has the variable $conn = mysqli_connect(“$dbhost” etc.)

Answer (score 1):

mysql_query is deprecated.

Use mysqli_query. Try:

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
$sql="SELECT count(user_id) AS total FROM account_users";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
// Associative array
$row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
echo "Rows found :" . $row['total'];
```